# SDL2 on Xcode Codesigning Issues

Tags: c++, c, xcode, sdl, code-signing

I just installed SDL2 on xcode. I am using the skeleton program that is provided on the SDL website and when I build and run the program builds but doesnt run. Xcode crashes. From much reading that I have done it is my understanding that I have to update the signature for SDL. Now Im a very beginner programmer as you can tell and I need to know exactly where this signature is located and how I update it. It looks like this is the new signature that I have to add:

```
$ codesign -f -s - SDL2
```

but where do I add this?

Can someone please give me very easy step by step instructions so I can get this done already?

Answer (score 0):

In

```
codesign -f -s - SDL2
```

Just replace SDL2 with the complete path of framework. For me it was :

```
codesign -f -s - /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/
```